# I want to duplicate observations (rows) in a tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am provided with the following tibble..

```
tibble(store="store a")
```

..and want to expand it with the same observation 30 times, like this:

```
tibble(store=rep("store a", 30))

# A tibble: 30 x 1
   store  
   <chr>  
 1 store a
 2 store a
 3 store a
 4 store a
 5 store a
 6 store a
 7 store a
 8 store a
 9 store a
10 store a
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `uncount()` in `tidyr`.

```
tidyr::uncount(tibble(store = "store a"), 30)

# # A tibble: 30 x 1
#    store  
#    <chr>  
#  1 store a
#  2 store a
#  3 store a
#  4 store a
#  5 store a
#  6 store a
#  7 store a
#  8 store a
#  9 store a
# 10 store a
# # … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: Thats it, i was wondering wether ``tidyr:uncount()`` would ever be usefull for me. Thanks:)

Comment: @lucaskr please do accept this answer instead of mine because, even though we reached the same conclusion separately, DarrenTsai posted it a few seconds before me. So I will delete my answer and only this will remain.

Comment: One more thing: The solution u gave here presumes that i initialize the tibble. The thing is, the tibble is the result of a ``group_by()%>%summarise()`` call and i want to pipe it further. By further i mean i want to extent it to 30 rows. You know any solution for that?

Comment: @lucaskr I think adding `%>% tidyr::uncount(30)` after your pipe code will work.

Comment: It works, great, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```r
a <- tibble(store="store a")
a[rep(1, 30),]
# A tibble: 30 x 1
   store  
   <chr>  
 1 store a
 2 store a
 3 store a
 4 store a
 5 store a
 6 store a
 7 store a
 8 store a
 9 store a
10 store a
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Comment: I was looking for a tidy version to fix it, but this is definitely doing the job, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `replicate` + `rbind` could work for you

```
do.call(rbind,replicate(30,df,simplify = FALSE))
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 30 x 1
   store
   <chr>
 1 store a
 2 store a
 3 store a
 4 store a
 5 store a
 6 store a
 7 store a
 8 store a
 9 store a
10 store a
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Comment: This does work, but I benchmark it at about 10 times slower than a simple  `a[rep(1,30),]`

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, `replicate`the whole data frame is slower than repeat the row index